# Adding new line of data to TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, textbox

I'm doing a chat client, and currently I have a button that will display data to a multi-line textbox when clicked. Is this the only way to add data to the multi-line textbox? I feel this is extremely inefficient, because if the conversation gets really long the string will get really long as well.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sent = chatBox.Text;
            displayBox.Text += sent + "\r\n";

        }
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue creating a simple TCP chat client. My solution was to just check the line count whenever I added a message and when it exceeded a certain threshold remove the oldest lines. I'm posting this as a comment because it's still pretty inefficient but it's an alternative to just simply adding.

Comment: i thought about that but there must be a better way

Comment: If you consider most simple chat applications that's pretty much how they work. Even thinking about something like AOL Instant Messenger chat windows just continued to get longer and longer. Basically the same concept.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

If you use WinForms:

Use the `AppendText(myTxt)` method on the `TextBox` instead (.net 3.5+):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sent = chatBox.Text;

        displayBox.AppendText(sent);
        displayBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

    }
```

Text in itself has typically a low memory footprint (you can say a lot within f.ex. 10kb which is "nothing"). The TextBox does not render all text that is in the buffer, only the visible part so you don't need to worry too much about lag. The slower operations are inserting text. Appending text is relatively fast.

If you need a more complex handling of the content you can use `StringBuilder` combined with the textbox. This will give you a very efficient way of handling text.

Comment: Or condensed version: displayBox.AppendText($"{sent}\r\n");

Answer (score 52):

Following are the ways

1. From the code (the way you have mentioned) ->

   ```
   displayBox.Text += sent + "\r\n";
   ```

   or

   ```
   displayBox.Text += sent + Environment.NewLine;
   ```
2. From the UI
   a) WPF

   ```
   Set TextWrapping="Wrap" and AcceptsReturn="True"
   ```

   Press Enter key to the textbox and new line will be created

   b) Winform text box

   ```
   Set TextBox.MultiLine and TextBox.AcceptsReturn to true
   ```

Comment: I was using a radTextBox and Environment.NewLine does not work in that but the \r\n does. This answer covers a few different methods that makes it more helpful all around.

Answer (score 3):

I find this method saves a lot of typing, and prevents a lot of typos.

```
string nl = "\r\n";

txtOutput.Text = "First line" + nl + "Second line" + nl + "Third line";
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this function to keep newest at top:

```
WriteLog("hello1");
WriteLog("hello2");
WriteLog("hello3");


public void WriteLog(string text)
{
    var last = txtLog.Text;
    txtLog.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("G") + ": " + text;
    txtLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    txtLog.AppendText(last);            
}
```

Will output this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't specified what front end (GUI technology) you're using it would be hard to make a specific recommendation.  In WPF you could create a listbox and for each new line of chat add a new listboxitem to the end of the collection.  This [link](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/implement-chat-window-via-winforms-t1324368.html) provides some suggestions as to how you may achieve the same result in a winforms environment.

Comment: what do you mean, i said C# its a form

Comment: I too develop in C#, however I do not use windows forms (winforms).  I use WPF and XAML.  I have also developed applications using MVC with HTML5 and Javascript that utilize C# for the business logic. Each of these graphical user interface technologies have different controls which you could repurpose for your chat window.

Comment: I assumed you were talking about WinForms but Alan is correct, just saying a C# form is somewhat ambiguous. You could have meant WinForm, WebForm, WPF... the list goes on of forms that can implement C# code.

Comment: yeah, i was actually being sincere when i said "what do you mean". I had no idea what you were talking about. I understand now though... thanks

Comment: OK.  Just for clarification, he has now tagged it as WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

C# - serialData is `ReceivedEventHandler` in `TextBox`.

```
SerialPort sData = sender as SerialPort;
string recvData = sData.ReadLine();

serialData.Invoke(new Action(() => serialData.Text = String.Concat(recvData)));
```

Now Visual Studio drops my lines. TextBox, of course, had all the correct options on.

Serial:

```
Serial.print(rnd);
Serial.( '\n' );  //carriage return
```