# How do I add New Line in text box based on value from Combo Box?

Tags: combobox, textbox, newline

I have crated Random Password Generator with options to select the length of password (between 8 and 20) and combination of password characters (Upper Case, Lower Case, Numbers and Special Characters).  Works FINE until I ask to generate more then one password.  I like user to be able to chose how many passwords they want to see in the Password box each password in new line.  Need help with to generate numbers of new random password based on value provided (selected) by cmbNPass.Text (ComboBox) into txtPass.Text (with each new password in new line)

Thank you,
Cheers!!!
Chirag Patel

Comment: What language are you using, can we see the code so we know what you have tried?

Comment: Private Sub cmdOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdOK.Click
        On Error Resume Next
        'Adds Line Numbers
        Dim sLine As String
        sLine = "Hello!"
        txtLine.Text = sLine
        'txtLine.Text = Textbox where lines will apper
        'cmbLNumber.Text = Numbers of line to print in the TextBox
        For i As Integer = 1 To Val(cmbLNumber.Text)
            txtLine.Text += Val(txtLine.Text) & vbNewLine
        Next
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a bit more explicit about what you are programming in?

I'm assuming you are in a microsoft world. Set the multiline property to true and use \r\n.

[Adding new line of data to TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318561/adding-new-line-of-data-to-textbox)

By the way, I would not use a password generator if you paid me. Consider this scenario:

Please give your user name______________
Your randomly generated password is !Hell0World#

I now have your login details in clear text.

Comment: I am using VB Express 2008.  I can send you a screen shot an code if you wish too.... Here is the code for the password generator...

Comment: If you are using vb the solution I gave should work. There's also a microsoft article... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f650cd1c-e006-433f-bb4f-59a894237878/newline-in-textbox?forum=isvvba

Comment: Private Sub cmdOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdOK.Click
        On Error Resume Next
        'Adds Line Numbers
        Dim sLine As String
        sLine = "Hello!"
        txtLine.Text = sLine
        'txtLine.Text = Textbox where lines will apper
        'cmbLNumber.Text = Numbers of line to print in the TextBox
        For i As Integer = 1 To Val(cmbLNumber.Text)
            txtLine.Text += Val(txtLine.Text) & vbNewLine
        Next
    End Sub